# Why does Z3 branching (find_nl_var_for_branching) skip real variables?

Tags: z3, smt

The Z3 function find_nl_var_for_branching (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/bba005154c2c753f0da108e39eb6abac2b3c7640/src/smt/theory_arith_nl.h#L719), which  "tries to find an integer variable for performing branching," skips real-valued variables.  Is there a fundamental reason for that which I am missing?  It seems to me that the only requirement for branching on real variables (in contrast to integers) is that probably the order of preference needs to be reconsidered (eg simply, always select randomly between real variables) to ensure all variables get branched eventually.

This seemed potentially like a straightforward enhancement to make, but since I'm pretty new to the z3 source and SMT solvers in general, figured I should ask first.